# XSLT foreach with attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

*What I would like to do is do a  transformation from XML to XML and
   keep `<variant_effect>` in its current state.  I will never know how
   many "effects" a given `<feature>` could have so each child will have
   0...n effect attributes.  I am not sure of the best/easiest method of doing this.*

Given an XML layout that has multiple feature within each document.

```
<feature>
  <seqid>12</seqid>
  <source>HGMD</source>
  <type>substitution</type>
  <start>9232268</start>
  <end>9232268</end>
  <score>.</score>
  <strand>+</strand>
  <id>HGMD_SNV_000001</id>
  <alias>HGVS:NM_000014.4:c.2998G-A,HGVS:NP_000005.2:p.V1000I</alias>
  <variant_seq>A</variant_seq>
  <reference_seq>T</reference_seq>
  <variant_effect>
    <feature_id effect="1">A2M</feature_id>
    <index effect="1">0</index>
    <sequence_variant effect="1">gene_variant</sequence_variant>
    <feature_type effect="1">gene</feature_type>
    <feature_id effect="2">CM980001</feature_id>
    <index effect="2">0</index>
    <sequence_variant effect="2">transcript_variant</sequence_variant>
    <feature_type effect="2">transcript</feature_type>
    <feature_id effect="3">CM980001</feature_id>
    <index effect="3">0</index>
    <sequence_variant effect="3">coding_sequence_variant</sequence_variant>
    <feature_type effect="3">mRNA</feature_type>
  </variant_effect>
  <sequence_context>CTAAATGAAACACAGCAGCTTACTCCAGAG,TCAAGTCCAAGGCCATTGGCTATCTCAACA</sequence_context>
</feature>
```

Using XSLT to move over all the tags over to a new XML document is
   straightforward, except for `<variant_effect>`.  When I use a
   `<xsl:for-each>` expression in different ways, I either get only a
   single section:

```
<feature>
  <!-other values -->
  <variant_effect>
    <feature_id>A2M</feature_id>
    <index effect>0</index>
    <sequence_variant>gene_variant</sequence_variant>
    <feature_type>gene</feature_type>
  </variant_effect>
</feature>
```

Or all of the variant_effect's from the entire file as one long dump in each `<feature>` section.
Example of one method I attempted:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="GVFClin/feature">

        <!- dealing with each sections first -->

        <variant_effect>  
            <xsl:for-each select="/GVFClin/feature/variant_effect/sequence_variant">
                <xsl:value-of select="/GVFClin/feature/variant_effect/sequence_variant"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </variant_effect>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

*Guess Im not really sure how to keep track of each element and print out all `<variant_effect>` "effects" for only a given node.*

*Any help or references to similar question already answer would be great, Thanks!*

Comment: I am pretty sure a template based stylesheet is the key to solve your problem. To help you with that you should show us the output you want for the input you posted, then we can help writing the templates.

Comment: This is my current [XSLT code](https://github.com/srynobio/Clinomic/blob/master/data/XML/GVF-CDA-GTR.xsl), if you do a super-find for "<!-- Working on this section -->", you can see where I'm at.

Comment: I Also added an [example](https://github.com/srynobio/Clinomic/blob/master/bin/test_hl7.xml) output for how the transformation work as of now.

Thanks!

Comment: You really should take a step back and learn about template-based processing (also called "push" processing) as an alternative to your for-each approach.  Start with the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which will copy input to output unmodified, and then add more-specific templates that handle things you _do_ want to modify.

Comment: I agree with the others above but also think that the original XML needs some work. The variant_effect element seems to contain several objects that for some reason isn't grouped. That would simplify the xslt work even if you stick to for-each.
I think it should look like this:
<variant_effect>
  <feature index="1" id="A2M" type="gene" sequence_variant="gene_variant" />
</variant_effect>
Then you would have something to loop over.